# Redirect to login when API returns authentication failure

Tags: identityserver4

I have a setup with IdentityServer4 and an API that run together as the same project, and an MVC client. This works fine but at some point the client makes a call to the API and an authentication error (401) is returned because the access token has somehow become invalid. In this scenario, I want the client to invoke the login page on the server so the user can re-enter their credentials and then redirect back to the client.

```
string accessToken = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())     
    client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://apiserver/method");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {

         string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         forum = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(content);
    } else {
         return Redirect(... url to server login with return URL here ...)
    }
}
```

I'm not clear how to generate the url to the server with the right path and query to authenticate correctly and return back to the client. I've looked through the documentation and samples but none seem to address this scenario.

I'm not clear how to generate the url to the server with the right path and query to authenticate correctly and return back to the client. I've looked through the documentation and samples but none seem to address this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you get unauthorized access status code 401 from the api, you have to first log the user out. By logging them out it will clear out the cookies and sign them out from the oidc as well. This will redirect the app to your login page as there will be no cookies to authenticate on the client.

```
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("oidc");
```

Another way is to check whether your access token has been expired beforehand i.e before making the api call. This will save you extra http call. But it depends on your application requirements.

Comment: That's it. Thanks! It wasn't obvious that signing out in response to an authentication issue would fix it but I wasn't thinking clearly. :-)